# Asp.Net 3.5 Button OnClientClick Argument

Tags: asp.net, button, onclientclick

I'm trying to call the MyJavascriptFunction(arg1) from an asp button and it's doesn't work...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMyButton" runat="server"
            OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Id", "MyJavascriptFunction({0})") %>' />
```

The html generated contains no OnClick event at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you write this method in your Page_Load event

```
Page.Databind();
```

and this button is under another data control ?

Comment: Yes, it is under another data control. Add this help me to find my problem. I was misspell the field in Eval...

Answer (score 2):

This is when you are doin in listview or data grid

```
<asp:button id="ButtonDownload" runat="server" Text="Download"
    OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("return downloadFile(\"{0}\")",Eval("QueryID")) %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, and might not work or it will need more escaping. but try something like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMyButton" runat="server"
            OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("MyJavascriptFunction(\"{0}\"", this.ClientID) %>' />
```

Note you need to use ClientID (rather than ID) to get the actual ID rendered in the HTML for your button.